# Colspan issue with plotly subplots - works with spanning across two columns, but not three

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am wanting to create a subplot with 4 rows and 3 columns using plotly subplots in VS Code. Each column for the first three rows is to contain an individual plot, whereas the fourth row will have one plot spanning three columns. This is the code I have so far, for which I intend to use the fig.add_trace command to add the individual plots:

fig = make_subplots(rows=4, cols=3,specs=[[{}, {}, {}],[{}, {}, {}],[{}, {}, {}],[{‘colspan’: 3}, None]])

However with this I get the following error: “The ‘specs’ argument to make_subplots must be a 2D list of dictionaries with dimensions (4 x 3). Received value of type <class ‘list’>: [[{}, {}, {}], [{}, {}, {}], [{}, {}, {}], [{‘colspan’: 3}, None]]”

I am unsure why this is - as far as I understand the specs is in the 4x3 arrangement. Interestingly, if I set the plot in the fourth row to span across only 2 rows (see below), the code works.

fig = make_subplots(rows=4, cols=3,specs=[[{}, {}, {}],[{}, {}, {}],[{}, {}, {}],[{‘colspan’: 2}, {}, None]])

Does anyone have an idea why this is not working for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you've only accounted for 2 columns and not 3 on the last row, so try changing your code to:

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=4, cols=3,specs=[[{}, {}, {}],[{}, {}, {}],[{}, {}, {}],[{‘colspan’: 3}, None, None]])
```